# Need assistance with t-sql query max date + distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Just like in the title I need some help with  t-SQL query to deliver a report. What I need to do is to pull data from client table and shipment table. Next the records must exclude those clients which have not done any shipments starting from `100` and must include the day of the last order made by the client.

OK lets clear what is the goal of this query.

[image]

I do not know if it is good idea but I have pasted an image from excel.
Anyway, as can you see at the moment I am pulling data that includes all of those shipments lately made but I am looking to find out how to exclude those clients whose booked more shipments and they starting from '100'.

And this is my query

```
SELECT  j.ClientName,
        j.ContactName, 
        j.PhoneMumber, 
        j.Email, 
        js.OrderNumb, 
        js.SentDate
FROM  Client j
outer apply (
        SELECT top 1 *
        FROM    Shipment js
        WHERE   js.ClientNum= j.ClientNUm
        ORDER BY
        js.SentDate DESC
    ) js
where j.ClientBur= 'HB'
```

Can you help me out to get on the right track and find solution?

Comment: When asking SQL question, it's always nice to include (1) relevant examples from you dataset, and (2) expected output from the supplied example data.

Comment: Have a look Tobb on the example above the sql query the record highlighted on red is the one I am looking to exclude from read as its starts from '100'

Comment: What does it mean "starts from 100"? are you talking about `OrderNum` column? is that a string or a number?

Comment: Exactly as I mentioned earlier I need to exclude all client records  where   OrderNum starts from '100'  and as you can see those are numbers the  rest is self-explanatory.

Comment: @piotr well, no, this is not self-explanatory. `OrderNum` looks like a number, but it might as well be stored as a string. And the solutions will be different for string and an int.

Comment: Come on @trailmax, it is pretty clear he means a filter on all OrderNums that match the pattern '100%'

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but I'm guessing you are probably looking for condition `Not like '100%'`

Something like this

```
select * -- whatever
from Client j 
where j.ClientBur= 'HB' 
      and j.OrderNum not like '100%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more OUTER APPLY to get TOP 1 row with `OrderNumb` started with `100` and then exclude them in WHERE statement:

```
SELECT  j.ClientName,
        j.ContactName, 
        j.PhoneMumber, 
        j.Email, 
        js.OrderNumb, 
        js.SentDate
FROM  Client j
outer apply (
        SELECT top 1 *
        FROM    Shipment js
        WHERE   js.ClientNum= j.ClientNUm
        ORDER BY
        js.SentDate DESC
    ) js
outer apply (
        SELECT top 1 *
        FROM    Shipment js
        WHERE   js.ClientNum= j.ClientNUm
                AND LEFT(js.OrderNumb,3) = '100' 
        ORDER BY js.SentDate DESC
    ) js100
WHERE j.ClientBur= 'HB' 
        AND js100.OrderNumb IS NULL
```